# Error: Could not find or load main class Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij with Maven, and I keep running into this problem:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME

I am also using JDK 1.7.0_60

My environmental variables are:

- `M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\Maven`
- `MAVEN_HOME = C:\Program Files\Maven`
- `M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin`

Before I was encountering this error when I would run the code:

> No valid Maven installation found. Either set the home directory in the configuration dialog or set the M2_HOME environment variable on your system.

I fixed it by setting the path manually in the maven settings of Intellij because M2_HOME was not being picked up. I have looked at many other posts but none have helped me yet.

Comment: Looks like you forgot `-` in front of `Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory`.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem where M2_HOME wasn't being picked up.  To resolve this, I also manually set the location by going into File->Settings->Maven->Runner and setting the VM Options to 

`-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\root\location\of\project\`.
*Included the config modification steps for anyone else having this issue*

As @Tunaki mentioned in a comment, make sure to have `-` in front of the command.